# How to call an identity server protected API resource from within ELSA workflow's SendHttpRequest activity using bearer token

Tags: identityserver4, elsa-workflows

I have configured my Elsa client app with Identity Server 4. Below is the extension method for Authentication.

```
 public static void AddCustomAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "myElsaApp";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";

                options.ClientId = "myElsaApp"; 
                options.ClientSecret = "secretpassword"; 
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                // request access to scopes
                ...

                // get claims
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            });

            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        }
```

And here is the extension method for Authorization

```
 public static void AddCustomAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
        }
```

I am calling both above extension methods in my Startup.cs
When I run the application, it asks for username and password. and after the successfull authentication I am expecting the access token from Identity Server 4 to be stored in my HttpContext.

**Objective**

I have a web API protected by identity server. Which means the client app (elsa app in my case) must send a bearer token to be able to call this API.

**My Approach**

I though I would be able to extract my access token from HttpContext which I can Inject in my client app. And then using that access token I can call any protected APIs. For this purpose I wanted to [extend the javascript](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/extensibility/extensibility-javascript) so that I can use **accessToken** function as expression evaluator for *Authorization* input field of **SendHttpRequest** activity in Elsa dashboard while designing the workflow. Here is the code for **GetAccessToken.cs**

```
public class GetAccessToken : INotificationHandler<EvaluatingJavaScriptExpression>
    {
        private HttpContext _HttpContext;
        public GetAccessToken(IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor)
        {
            _HttpContext = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        }
        public async Task Handle(EvaluatingJavaScriptExpression notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var engine = notification.Engine;
            var accessToken = await _HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Cookies", "access_token");
            engine.SetValue("accessToken", accessToken);
        }
    }
```

To inject HttpContext following line was added to my Startup.cs

`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

**Problem**

When I run the code and trigger the workflow that is supposed to evaluate the JavaScript expression. I get the following error message.

[image]

Looks like the HttpContextAccessor is returning null.

I need to know the best way to call an API from within Elsa workflow using SendHttpRequest while carrying Bearer token.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your approach to make available the access token via JS and then using it from the `SendHttpRequest` looks good from what I can see. However, it is important to realize that the HTTP Context is only available when your workflow is invoked within that same context. In other words, if the workflow were triggered by e.g. a timer, there is no HTTP context.

Comment: Thanks for reply Spike. How would you solve this problem without the HTTP context? My workflow is invoked by another DISPATCHER workflow that searches for all workflows matching a specific TAG. This means my workflow will never have HTTP context. But I still need an access token to be able to call the protected APIs.

Comment: Could you let me know if you solved your problem? I am facing the same scenario as you have. 

As you can save your access token in a database or memory. The static dictionary could solve this issue. If you have a single access token for all users, then you can save the access token in a static property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you trying to implement some kind of [machine-to-machine](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#machine-to-machine-communication) interaction.
In this case you can consider using [client credentials flow](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#refclientcredentialsquickstart) instead of `authorization code` flow which you are currently using.
That means you need to add another [client](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#defining-the-client) into IdentityServer4 config with corresponding settings. And then instead of passing your frontend's accessToken everywhere you start using new IdentityServer client, server-side one in this particular case.

Talking about disadvantages. Well, most likely you need some information about current user and your new server-side accessToken won't have such kind of details inside (because it's not a user who is starting a process here, but a service).
In this case I might suggest adding another method or controller with some new parameters like `userId`, for example.  This method or controller can be made accessible from only specified IdentiyServer4 clients through [policies](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#authorization-at-the-api).